# Multiple tags separated by commas don't works in textarea fields

Tags: solspace-tag

i've an issue using Tag with Channel Form in front. I've Tag v.4.2.8 and it's setted in the CP

[image: Tag CP settings]

and the code is

```
{exp:channel:form channel="spots" class="form-horizontal" return="spot/ENTRY_ID/URL_TITLE" }
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-1">Titolo</label>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Inserisci il titolo della tua domanda" name="title" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          {field:spot_desc}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-xs-1">Tags</label>
          <div class="col-md-11">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" name="tags"></textarea>
            <p class="help-block">Separa ogni tag con la virgola</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    {/exp:channel:form}
```

But when try to submit tags commas separate

```
example, taga, commas
```

the results is only one tag with the commas

```
<a href="">example, taga, commas</a>
```

Where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could always just use the `{field:tag_fieldtype_short_name}` tag, which Solspace recommends in their docs. If that doesn't work you can always look at the page source after it parses and see the way Solspace requires the field.

[Docs](http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/using_with_channel_form/) for using the Tag module in channel form.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, you would need to use the [**Tag Widget**, i.e. `{field:my_tag_custom_field_name}`](http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/using_with_channel_form/) to add tags from a Channel Form in which you're creating a new channel entry.

What happens in the background is that tags are added to a textarea field with `name="my_tag_custom_field_name"`, with each tag on a separate line (newline-separated). If you have a regular textarea field with your Tag field's name in the `name=""` attribute, you can also enter new tags as long as each tag is on their own line. This happens to be a coincidence that it works, since Channel Form should use the Tag Widget.

Alternatively, you can use `{exp:tag:form}` to add tags to a *pre-existing* entry: http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/form/. In this case, you would have to create an entry first, *then* add tags to the newly created entry.